# Admin toolbar CSS broken by theme

Tags: 8, theming, toolbar

I'm facing issue with Admin toolbar. Every time I create theme and define default style guide for typography eg.:

```
...
h2 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
...
```

Admin toolbar's CSS is taking these style rules. I've tried to look for patch that would fix Admin toolbar CSS styles so it's more nested that my style guide will not override it but I didn't find anything.

My theme's libraries are restricted only to theme so they should not affect admin pages *(and yes I understand that Admin Toolbar is also part of my theme and it's not categorized as an admin page)*

Is there a way to define default typography **h1, h2, h3, ... h6, p ...** *(like when you do website without CMF/ CMS)* and do not affect Admin toolbar's CSS styles?

Comment: You could prefix your styles with a wrapper class from `page.html.twig`.  Depends on the theme, but something like `.layout-container p {}`.

Comment: this is something i'm trying to avoid because then on specific places where i need a bit customization for `h2` tag i need to write a lot of useless (and nested) css.

Comment: Could you just target the toolbar for those header classes that are being affected, that way your global style won't override your `.toolbar` classes?

Comment: I was thinking about patching Admin Toolbar’s css to be more nested so my global styles wont override it. But im not sure if it’s a good approach.

Comment: Well... you're doing something wrong somewhere else. Adding those styles should not affect the admin toolbar.

Comment: @NoSssweat but it does. I specify my library as theme-only and it affect the Admin toolbar css. The only solution looks like nest my h1...h6 styles into some wrapper class.